# Remove scopes on GCE to prevent metadata access

Tags: scope, google-compute-engine, metadata

In relation to this question: [Limit access to metadata on GCE instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660924/limit-access-to-metadata-on-gce-instance)
removing all scopes would disable access to metadata on GCE.
Using

```
gcloud beta compute instances set-scopes myinstance --no-scopes --no-service-account --project "myproject" --zone zone
```

however, does not disable access.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit access to metadata on GCE instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60660924/limit-access-to-metadata-on-gce-instance)

Comment: No it does not.